# Why angular-material adds <link> tag which makes using SASS version impossible

Tags: angular-material

I am using angular-material.sass to compile my app.css but it doesn't work.
Cause of it is `<link>` tag created by JSPM.
Angular material has in package.son this lines:

```
"shim": {
  "angular-material": {
    "deps": [
      "./angular-material.css!"
    ]
  }
}
```

It makes JSPM create `<link>` tag after my app.css and lots of overwrites does not work.
Every Angular Material version update I has to go to angular-material.js and delete these lines:

```
"deps ./angular-material.css!";
```

and after that it stops loading it's CSS. Annoying.
Why CSS framework forcefully adds itself to HTML? Is it 'feature"? For me it's a bug